# Half Transparent layer on application screen UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Is there a way to add semi transparent layer for the application in UWP?
In normal .NET there is a possibility, but in UWP I cant find it.

I need this behavior, for make the whole application inactive except one control, and display a tooltip next to the control. It is need for tuturial in application

Thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm imagining you need some sort of BlockUI/UnBlockUI behavior, not sure if there's a 3rd party for that, but you can be creative in order to achieve that.

By taking advantage of **ZIndex**, **Opacity**, **DependencyProperty** and some **event handling**, you can achieve that.

xaml

```
<Page x:Name="root"
     x:Class="App1.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Canvas Background="AliceBlue">
        <Rectangle  Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.ZIndex="{Binding BlockerZIndex, ElementName=root}"  Width="180" Height="200" Fill="White" Opacity="0.5"/>
        <Button Canvas.ZIndex="1" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="70" Content="Send Email" Width="150" Height="50" Background="Blue" Foreground="Black" />
        <Button Canvas.ZIndex="1"  Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="140" Content="Print Receipt" Width="150" Height="50" Background="Blue" Foreground="Black" />
        <Button x:Name="BlockUnBlockUIButton" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Canvas.Top="210" Width="150" Height="50" Background="Blue" Foreground="Black" Click="BlockUnBlockUIButton_OnClick" >
            <TextBlock Text="Block/UnBlock UI" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Block/Unblock UI"/>
        </Button>
    </Canvas>
</Page>
```

code-behind

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;

namespace App1
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BlockerZIndexProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                nameof(BlockerZIndex),
                typeof(int),
                typeof(MainPage),
                new PropertyMetadata(2));

        public int BlockerZIndex
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(BlockerZIndexProperty);
            set => SetValue(BlockerZIndexProperty, value);
        }

        private void BlockUnBlockUIButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BlockerZIndex = BlockerZIndex == 1 ? 2 : 1;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thx Mate, But it is not UWP code. I think it is working under WPF, not on UWP.

Comment: My apologies, I mixed up my tagging thought it's wpf, please see edits, I made a UWP version of it, you need to use canvas in this case.